# Make API call and database operations atomic

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, entity-framework-6, atomic

I want to do the following:

- Begin a transaction
- insert data to a database
- After the insert, submits data to an API endpoint with the newly added rows' primary key
- Then commit the transaction

If the insert fails, nothing will be done and everything is rollbacked. The problem is I don't have a good way to rollback the API request if the committing of the transaction fails because it is not a database operation. The only thing I can think of is delete the data from the endpoint. Is there a better way? I am using entity framework. Thanks.

Comment: Submit the data to the API endpoint after you have saved the changes with EF.

Comment: @Sir Rufo yes. The problem is when the submition to the data endpoint failed, I need to rollback the database, which I can no longer do if I save the changes.

Comment: You have the keys of the rows, so you can remove them if the API call fails

Comment: @SirRufo what if the service calling the API fails right after it finds out (catches an exception) that the API call failed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So if I have understood correctly, you only want to commit to the DB if the API call was successful, but can't call the API until you have the DB generated primary Key from the DB insert.

So this would lead to a kind of 2 phase commit type of approach, but what happens if the insert is successful, the API call is successful, but the DB commit fails?  (if happens!)

Therefore, I think that you should consider to instead implement the **Saga design Pattern.**

This is design for complex distributed systems, especially using microservices, where you need to ensure data consistency across different distributed systems.
Basically you build a kind of chain of transactions which need to be executed in order.  You then go through them one by one and if successful then you move onto the next.

But, for every transaction you also have a compensating transaction.  So that if a transaction fails then you work backwards through your list executing all the compensating transactions one by one until in the end you have the same initial state.

There are different ways of doing this such as the Choreography-based saga or the Orchestration-based saga.
You can find more details and a better explanation here:
https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html